# Which number from 1 till 64 is the debug's signal number?

Tags: bash, signals

The syntax for the trap statement is straightforward:
trap [COMMANDS] [SIGNALS]

```
trap -l
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL   5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT  7) SIGBUS   8) SIGFPE   9) SIGKILL 10) SIGUSR1
11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGUSR2 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM
16) SIGSTKFLT   17) SIGCHLD 18) SIGCONT 19) SIGSTOP 20) SIGTSTP
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGURG  24) SIGXCPU 25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGIO   30) SIGPWR
31) SIGSYS  34) SIGRTMIN    35) SIGRTMIN+1  36) SIGRTMIN+2  37) SIGRTMIN+3
38) SIGRTMIN+4  39) SIGRTMIN+5  40) SIGRTMIN+6  41) SIGRTMIN+7  42) SIGRTMIN+8
43) SIGRTMIN+9  44) SIGRTMIN+10 45) SIGRTMIN+11 46) SIGRTMIN+12 47) SIGRTMIN+13
48) SIGRTMIN+14 49) SIGRTMIN+15 50) SIGRTMAX-14 51) SIGRTMAX-13 52) SIGRTMAX-12
53) SIGRTMAX-11 54) SIGRTMAX-10 55) SIGRTMAX-9  56) SIGRTMAX-8  57) SIGRTMAX-7
58) SIGRTMAX-6  59) SIGRTMAX-5  60) SIGRTMAX-4  61) SIGRTMAX-3  62) SIGRTMAX-2
63) SIGRTMAX-1  64) SIGRTMAX     

trap "ls" debug
Desktop      Templates    Documents
```

Which number from 1 till 64 is the debug's signal number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap) seems to be somewhat confusing here, as it seems to imply that all the command takes are signal names or numbers:

> `trap [-lp] [arg] [sigspec …]`
>
> The `-l` option causes the shell to print a list of signal names and their corresponding numbers. Each *sigspec* is either a signal name or a signal number.

But of course `DEBUG`, `EXIT`, `ERR`, and `RETURN` are not actual signals, but conditions in the shell. The online help text is slightly different, but not that much better, although it mentions "signals or other conditions".

The [text in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_28) is much clearer, it explicitly states that the condition is *either* a signal, *or* `EXIT`:

> `trap [action condition...]`
>
> The condition can be EXIT, 0 (equivalent to EXIT), or a signal specified using a symbolic name, without the SIG prefix, as listed in the tables of signal names in the *<signal.h>* header

So, `EXIT` has number zero, the others are nonstandard extensions and don't seem to have numerical equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no debug signal, this is something else you could read more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html). 
`If a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed before every simple command, for command, case command, select command, every arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in a shell function`